# SwiftUI: How can I get Just time value (Int) from DatePicker and Date?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, swiftui

I am a student building an App for the user can set a time from DatePicker so whenever the user opens the App over the set time every day, the user will get some information.

But right now I am stuck with how to just get time value that is an Int from DatePicker and just time value from Date(), so I can compare two different values to judge if the user opens the App over the set time?

Here is a part of my code.

```
@AppStorage("MissionStartTime") var missionStartTime = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: .init(hour: 8), matchingPolicy: .strict)!
var body: some View {
    Form {
        DatePicker("", selection: $missionStartTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
        }
}
```

I storage the default time value in the AppStorage wrapper.
The user picks a time from DatePicker.

I am still learning SwiftUI, so there might be something I misunderstand.
And this also is the first time I ask questions on StackOverflow.
Please help me. Anything is welcome

Comment: This article might help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-dates (scroll down to ["Again, DateComponents comes to the rescue"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-dates#:~:text=again%2C%20datecomponents%20comes%20to%20the%20rescue))

Comment: @aheze OMG! Thanks a lot. I can't believe I didn't look carefully at that article. This solves everything. Thanks!!

Comment: You can simply use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` to convert a `Date` to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can not store Date objects in UserDefaults. You can get the string format of time with DateFormatter if that helps.

```
@State var date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: .init(hour: 8), matchingPolicy: .strict)!
@State var timeString = ""

private func formatTime() {
    var timeFormatter : DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "tr_TR") // your locale here
        return formatter
    }
    
    timeString = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
}

var body: some View {
    Form {
        DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            .onChange(of: date, perform: { value in
                formatTime()
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: So it means I have to call the func every time the user has changed with the DatePicker right?

Comment: I believe so. You can call onChange method to DatePicker.